# Creating a document from url javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

This is what I've tried:

```
function createDocumentz() {
    var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('http://www.moviemeter.nl/film/270',null,'html');
    return doc;
}
```

Even though a document gets created,  if I run this with Firebug it says that the body node has no childnodes, any idea why?

Comment: Because you haven't appended any to body.

Comment: Maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738046/what-for-to-use-document-implementation-createhtmldocument) can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you assume that you can use `createHTMLDocument()` to download and parse a HTML file from the URL you've passed as the first parameter. That is not the case, `createHTMLDocument()` always creates an empty document.

Also, the parameters you've passed to the function are those of [`createDocument()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMImplementation.createDocument). `createHTMLDocument()` takes only one parameter, the document title. But even if you'd use `createDocument()`, the first parameter is the URI of the *namespace*, not the source document.

Unfortunately there's no way to download and manipulate external web site's HTML using JavaScript alone. The closest you can get is displaying the document in an iframe.

Comment: It's now possible to download and manipulate the document. You can't, however, set it's `Document.URL` unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot get the content from another website, this way.

If it did, it would have lead to cross site scripting.

All you would get is an empty document, due to the browser's policy, which of course has an empty body.

You can use an Iframe & set the source to the same...