# get dom from html string code without executing it

Tags: javascript

I need to parse a html string to get a node in special, and discard others like script tags

For example I use this code;

```
//I get the htmlCode from a textArea
htmlCode = '<video>'+
               '<source src="/media/video.oga">'+
               '<source src="/media/video.m4v">'+
               '<script src="evilscript.js"></script>'+
           '</video>';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = htmlCode;
```

And from there I can access the nodes of the div and discard the unnecesary; but I realize in network tab that the assignment launches requests of the sources of the video. And I don't want to make any request, because any malicious script can be in the htmlCode. So how could I modify the htmlCode without launching httprequests?

Comment: What is the original task?

Comment: it's for use in a chrome extension, to hide the code inside a gif and be able to show it

Comment: *"because any malicious script can be in the htmlCode"*. Note that the HTML DOM specification explicitly says that `<script>` elements are not evaluated when set via `innerHTML`. http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0

Comment: @FelixKling—I think that might be because HTML5 just documents how innerHTML was implemented, firstly by Microsoft and then others. I'm not sure it was specifically because of security implications (thought it might well have been, just that it came from a time when MS wasn't particularly concerned with things like that), it might be just for convenience  to store and re–use HTML fragments without worrying about stripping out script elements.

Comment: By the way I found another answer which responds my question
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/11530238/2359536](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11530238/2359536)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought of documentFragment but it cannot use innerHTML, it uses appendChild.

So it came to my mind `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()`.

So I tested it and it works. It doesn't make any http-requests from the sources.

This is my code now:

```
var dom = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
dom.body.innerHTML = '<video>'+
           '<source src="/media/video.oga">'+
           '<source src="/media/video.m4v">'+
           '<script src="evilscript.js"></script>'+
       '</video>';
```

And from here I can access the dom.

Comment: Do you have a specification reference for why innerHTML works like this on a document created by *document.implementation.createHTMLDocument*, but not in any other case? I have tracked down various references, but none mention the different behaviour of innerHTML.

Comment: Well, [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-DOM-Level-2-20000510/html.html#ID-1019015399) it says that `createHTMLDocument` return a HTMLDocument Object. And [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0) it says that apply `innerHTML` on an element set the new childrens `ownerDocument` to the current document. So I think that that's the difference of the behaviours. When set the same ownerDocument they make httprequests.

Comment: Perhaps it's because the domain is *null* (empty string really), and therefore resources aren't retrieved to prevent cross site issues?